# R - Why I couldn't use text() function for my plot in R?

Tags: r, text, label

I created a data.frame from the IMF data about population dynamics by countries (World Economic Outlook):

```
   Country Afghanistan Albania Algeria Angola Antigua.and.Barbuda    Argentina Armenia Aruba Australia  
1    1980        <NA>   2.672  18.666  8.910               0.068   27.950    <NA>  <NA>    14.802      
2    1981        <NA>   2.726  19.246  9.151               0.068   28.450    <NA>  <NA>    15.039
```

Then I created a plot for Argentina:

```
plot(mydata$Country, mydata$Argentina)
```

And tried to text the data labels:

```
text(x = mydata$Country,y = mydata$Argentina,labels = mydata$Argentina,cex=0.2)
```

But I don't see anything:(

Contrary, I could do it very easy in mtcars:

```
plot(a$mpg, a$hp)
text(a$mpg, a$hp, a$hp)
```

What's the problem with my example?

Comment: Are you trying to show the values (27.95 and 28.45) on the plot? Your code already does that. You just have to increase `cex` to see it.

Comment: Thanks, but... no way
plot(mydata$Country, mydata$Argentina)
text(mydata$Country,mydata$Argentina,mydata$Argentina,cex=2)

I don't see any labels:(

Answer (score 0):

Aziz, in his comment, seems to be right. If you run:

```
## This is the data
mydata <- data.frame(Country = 1980:1981, Argentina= c(27.95, 28.54))
## This is the plot
plot(mydata$Country, mydata$Argentina)
## This writes text in the plot
text(x = mydata$Country,y = mydata$Argentina,labels = mydata$Argentina,cex=1)
```

you will indeed see the figures corresponding to Argentina written as text in your plot.

Comment: Thank you. Right.
In that example it's correct - I see the labels.
But with my data.frame from IMF WEO I couldn't do it:
Maybe in terms of the format of data?
Because - 'head(mydata$Argentina)'
And I receive the answer: '[1] "27.950" "28.450" "28.930" "29.340" "29.840" "30.350"'
With quotation

Comment: Then, it might be that the column Argentina contains character and not numeric values. In this case, though, the problem should be with the plot, not with the text. Try to do `mydata <- mydata %>% mutate(Argentina = Argentina %>% as.numeric())` before everything else.

Comment: Thanks @Roland
It works!
But how could I mutate the whole matrix, I mean all countries, not only Argentina?

Comment: Starts to deviate from the original question. Would you mind closing this one, and open a new one, for the sake of clarity for the other users?